# extracting 5x5 patch from image around a pixel coordinate

Tags: python, image, opencv

```
I = cv.imread('test.png')
IB = I[:,:,0]
coords = corner_peaks(corner_harris(IB))
patch = IB[coords[1,0]-2:coords[1,0]+3,coords[1,1]-2:coords[1,1]+3]
print(patch)
```

if the interest point is not around boundary then it is working ok, but at boundary it is not working properly(patch is having smaller size). I guess it requires padding at boundaries.(not sure) 
Is there an easier method to do this? or to make it work at boundaries too?

Edit: i added following , it seems to work. will update if some problem occurs. If this can be solved with some inbuilt function then it would be good, kindly tell if it can be done using some function.

```
coords = coords +2
IBpadded = cv.copyMakeBorder(IB, 2, 2, 2, 2, cv.BORDER_REFLECT)
```

Comment: I think you have 1 of 3 choices. 1- mirror the image at the boundaries, 2- extend the image at the boundaries, or completely disregard patches that touch the boundaries. All can be done with if statements before you extract your patch. What are you using the patches for? For me mirroring the image seems the most natural, cause that is how convolution is done on finite-support 1-D signals(they reproduce the signal along the real line).

Comment: @FakherMokadem the patch i get from image, i will cross correlate with another patch.